# How to start typing text right to icon inside a input text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to reproduce this: [input icon type search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7DAK.png)

My result so far: [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Rhf.png)

My question is: How can I put this input element to start typing the text to the right of the icon as in the first image?

I've tried to change the type element to display the icon to  (Not work), tried  (Not work). I'm using Styled Components.

That's my CSS:

```css
import styled from "styled-components";

export const DivSearch = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 90px;
  margin-top: 27px;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  align-self: flex-end;
`;

export const Icon = styled.img`
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 7px;
`;

export const PlusIcon = styled(Icon)`
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: flex;
  padding-left:10px;
  filter: invert(100%);
`;

export const SearchIcon = styled(Icon)`
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: flex;
  filter: invert(27%) sepia(95%) saturate(2117%) hue-rotate(208deg) brightness(112%) contrast(101%);
`;

export const Input = styled.input`
  width: 296px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #cccfde;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-right: 15px;

  ::placeholder {
    /* padding-left: 35px; */
    color: #9196ab;
    padding-left:25px;
  }
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #888888;
    outline-style: none !important;
    ::placeholder {
      color: transparent;
    }
    &:hover {
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #888888;
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you position the search icon, you could just add left padding to the input like so:

```
padding-left: 20px;
```

Comment: That's my class:

class Search extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DivSearch>
        <SearchIcon src="/assets/icons/search.svg"></SearchIcon>
        <Input placeholder="Buscar" type="search"></Input>
        <NewJourneyButton></NewJourneyButton>
      </DivSearch>
    );
  }
}
export default Search;

Comment: I set the icon inside the input element.

Comment: @LucasBrandão, I would position the icon absolutely within the `input`, and add left padding to the input itself. Don't forget to relatively position the icon's parent element.

Comment: Solve it just setting padding-left:25px in the input element. I don't need to put the icon inside the component's input; Thank You @Ryan!

Comment: @LucasBrandão, Happy to help =] Accepting my answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Got it! Done! Thanks again.